# How does the leveling system work?

Tags: a-world-of-keflings

When you assign a Kefling a job, they will eventually level up.  What does this mean?  Will they work faster now?

Also, what is being leveled up?  If I take a level 3 Stone Miner and put them on lumber-jacking or gathering, do they have to start over from level 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but i still wanted to answer it because I recently started this game and was asking myself the same question,
and I recognized the following changes:
-They can carry for example more pieces of wood
-They seem to collect faster
-They seem to walk faster

Yes they have a diffrent level for each job.
Only the "Gatherer Kefling" of the diffrent items has the same level.
So if you have a lot of keflings you could let one kefling farm wood and drop it next to the tree, and let another kefling collect it.
So the 2. kefling has the Gathering job that counts for diffrent materials.